# Complete list of maps and modes for anti-air vehicles

Tags: battlefield-4

I want to make progress with anti-air vehicles but I don't have the complete list of maps and modes for anti-air vehicles.

Bonus points for an answer that includes all platforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of my experience, it is best to play and unlock upgrades in conquest large mode, since in these modes you will be able to find lots of air crafts to destroy.

Maps and spawn location:(these are conquest large unless specified)

- Seige of Shanghai: Has 2 MAA in Obliteration mode.
- Paracel Storm: 1 MAA, located at B
- Operation Locker: No MAA, no aircraft either.
- Flood Zone: MAA only in rush mode.
- Golmud Railway: 1 MAA per team
- Dawnbreaker: 1 MAA per team
- Hainan Resort: 1 MAA per team
- Lancang Dam: 1 MAA per team
- Rougue Transmission: One MAA will spawn at C after capture, one MAA per team
  (CQ Large and Obliteration)
- Zavod 331: 1 MAA per team

A word of advice, if you are looking for fast unlocks, when searching for a server type in keyword "instant" or "fast", and look for those that have "instant/fast vehicle respawns", the lowest it can be set at is 25% of normal respawn time, the lower the better. If you manage to get into an MAA on those servers you will feel like air crafts never stop coming.

Best maps for MAA:

- Golmud Railway: High visibility, no cover for air crafts
- Paracel Storm: High visibility, some cover for air crafts, risk being destroyed by c4
- Lancang Dam: High visibility, no cover for air crafts

PS: I play on PC, but I am almost certain that they are the same for consoles.

Comment: Flood Zone does have a MAA on Rush mode

Comment: Siege of Shanghai also has 2 in Obliteration. I think youre missing some others, but I couldn't find a complete list to post as an answer

Comment: Ya, I mainly play conquest large so I posted for those that I am aware of. Updated, thanks

Comment: I am pretty sure CQ large Rogue Transmission has a MAA on each team and an extra spawns at C after capture.  Each team definitely has one in Rogue Transmission Obliteration as well.  I don't think this a good question anyway, as the answer is basically every map except Operation Locker/Metro and small map game modes probably has at least one per team.

Comment: @turbo - you are correct on both counts for Rogue. Not every map on large modes has them (Shanghai CQ Large doesn't), and for the ones that have only one, spawn locations are helpful. Plus, the X360/PS3 versions are different, I'm fairly sure.

Comment: @Ssumner That's true, but really, nearly every map has one per team in CQ/Obliteration. If you play 2 rounds, of either game mode you're bound to find one.  Maybe this would be better as "Which Conquest Flags spawn an MAA in each map?" as you point out the spawn locations are helpful.  And Different? I doubt they would purposely make different vehicle spawns in different versions of the game..

Comment: @turbo - not true - BF3 had several maps that didn't have AA *at all* in the 360/PS3 versions due to the smaller map size. And the ones that did did occasionally show up in different places

Comment: @Ssumner That's not to say the differences in versions of BF4 will be the same as BF3. As far as I'm aware, all that is missing from the PS3/360 version (relative to this issue) is the higher player counts. I believe the maps are the same.  I don't see anything about the maps being smaller/different in [this article](http://www.nowgamer.com/features/2166575/battlefield_4_currentgen_vs_nextgen.html) nor any others I've skimmed.

Comment: I ve compared Seige of Shanghai and Hainan Resort, I wasn't able to find a difference in the actual maps (pc vs console)